# how to select max value according to the combination of three columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, subquery, inner-join

I am working on one query and got stuck in to that.

I have a sample data here

```
Name   Main_Model    Sub_Model     Sub_Sub_Model
===============================================
Ver1    1             0               0
ver2    1             0               0
ver1    1             2               0
ver2    1             1               0
ver1    2             0               0
ver2    1             1               1
ver1    2             2               1
```

with this data I have to select a maximum Model number. So for example

The maximum model number for Version 1 i.e. ver1 is

```
 Name   Main_Model    Sub_Model     Sub_Sub_Model
 ===============================================
 Ver1    2            2               1
```

for version 2 it would be

```
 Name   Main_Model    Sub_Model     Sub_Sub_Model
 ===============================================
 Ver2    1            1               1
```

I have tried inner joins but no luck. I am really confuse about it's logic.
Please guide so that I can complete this task.

Thank you

Comment: What when you have data like `Ver2 1 20 20`?

Comment: that time ver2 1  20  20 would be the maximum model if Model_sub has the highest 20 as a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rank rows with window function and get ranks where it is 1:

```
;with cte as(select *, row_number() over(partition by name
                                         order by main_model desc, 
                                                  sub_model desc,
                                                  sub_sub_model desc) rn
             from table)
select * from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I tried it but it's not giving me 1 row with maximum model_number:(

Comment: Elaborate what it gives and show what it shoud give. Elaborate how do you calculate max value for 3 columns...

Comment: Sorry...was my bad..I worked fine...Thank You so much

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to rank each row:

```
;WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT      Name, Main_Model, Sub_Model, Sub_Sub_Model
                    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Main_Model DESC, Sub_Model DESC, Sub_Sub_Model DESC)
        FROM        my_table
    )

SELECT  *
FROM    cte
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: your's is the same as the above. And it worked for me. Thank you so much for you help. I really appreciate it.